# Как получить ConnectionString из DbContext'а EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper, entity-framework-core

> Это краткий перевод вопроса [How to get ConnectionString from EF7
>   DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33127296/5752652)

Я использую EF core 2.0 для типовых CRUD операций и одновременно с этим Dapper для более сложных и быстрых запросов.

В файле startup.cs я делаю инъекцию `DbContext` в репозитории слоя DAL для работы EF, а dapper для работы использует connection string. Я хочу делать из DbContext'а EF получить строку для вставки в запрос Dapper.

Как я могу получить connection string из DbContext?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33127296/5752652

Comment: Интересно, а есть ли какая-то разница с тем, чтобы в startup.cs сразу пробрасывать в конструктор `Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionname")`?

Answer (score 1):

В EF.Core можно использовать:

```
var conn = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
ConnectionString = conn?.ConnectionString;
conn?.Dispose();
```